# Find the sum of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{3^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

$$ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{3^n} $$

The sum should be $\frac{27}{4}$, but how do you calculate it ? Can someone give me an approach on how to do it?

thanks!

Comment: you can try it with partial sums

Comment: or do not, just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the power series
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{2n+2}}{3^n} = \frac{3z^2}{3-z^2} $$
has a radius of convergence equal to $\rho=\sqrt{3}$. This allows us to differentiate both sides twice, then evaluate them at $z=1$, getting:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{3^n} = \left.\frac{54(1+z^2)}{(3-z^2)^3}\right|_{z=1}=\frac{27}{2}. $$
Now it is enough to divide by $2$ both sides.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{3^n}=2\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{n^2}{3^n}+3\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{n}{3^n}+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{3^n}$$
On the other hand, if $|x|<1$, then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
as a result
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
 and
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$$